# Multiple offset in same commitSync

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm doing manual `commitSync` to Kafka, and I notice in the DSL they use a simple `Map` and not `MultiMap`, so I guess then every time I invoke

```
consumer.commitSync(Map.of(topicPartition, new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset())))
```

Is just for a single record in the partition.

Any chance to send two offsets of the same `topicPartition` in the same `commitSync`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, committing an offset in Kafka implicitly commits *all offsets* before that!

Comment: You're absolutely right!, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Map, so no, you cannot have multiple instances of the same `topicPartition` key.

The offset is a single number. If you were able to commit multiple, then your consumer (in the same group) would always have to start reading from the greatest of those values.

You can commit offsets for other TopicPartitions, however, in one commit call, or you can commit the same value to **other** consumer groups using a differently configured Consumer instance.